# Disable javascript facet in a m2e project

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'd like to disable the Javascript Facet (and remove the Javascript builder) from a Maven-driven Eclipse project.
Is there any way I can configure the maven-eclipse-plugin to do so?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, clean the configuration with **mvn eclipse:clean**, it will remove all configuration from the .project file.

Then make a new one with **mvn eclipse:eclipse**, just with the configuration and dependencies on your pom.xml.

EDIT:
And configure the project natures that you need:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
            <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</projectnature>
        </projectnatures>
        <additionalProjectnatures>
            [... the ones you need or empty...]
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
        </additionalProjectnatures>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: We open the maven project from eclipse, and the first time we open it does not contain any `.project` file. It's m2e that when creates all the eclipse project configuration files add to them also the javascript nature and features. I would like to know how to disable it.